# Formatar colunas - selecionar informação específica

Tags: lista, unix

Caros usuários, tenho um arquivo grande com as seguintes colunas

```
chr10_46938     EXON=28/28      STRAND=-1       ENSP=ENSGALP00000004070 SIFT=tolerated(0.38) 
chr10_46966     EXON=28/28      STRAND=-1       DOMAINS=Low_complexity_(Seg):Seg        SIFT=tolerated(0.66)    ENSP=ENSGALP00000004070   
chr10_46987     EXON=28/28      STRAND=-1       SIFT=tolerated(0.93)    ENSP=ENSGALP00000004070
chr10_47071     ENSP=ENSGALP00000004070 SIFT=tolerated(0.97)    EXON=28/28      STRAND=-1
chr10_47164     EXON=28/28      STRAND=-1       DOMAINS=Low_complexity_(Seg):Seg        SIFT=tolerated(0.37)    ENSP=ENSGALP00000004070
chr10_47466     ENSP=ENSGALP00000004070 SIFT=tolerated(0.11)    STRAND=-1       EXON=28/28    DOMAINS=PROSITE_profiles:PS50196,Pfam_domain:SSF50729
```

Eu quero selecionar apenas a primeira coluna e a informação `SIFT=tolerated(..)`, mas esta não se encontra em colunas fixas, exemplo coluna 2. Como selecionar somente esta informação que desejo para ter por exemplo o seguinte *output*:

```
chr10_46938     SIFT=tolerated(0.38)  
chr10_46966     SIFT=tolerated(0.66)   
chr10_46987     SIFT=tolerated(0.93)  
chr10_47071     SIFT=tolerated(0.97)  
chr10_47094     SIFT=tolerated(1)            
chr10_47164     SIFT=tolerated(0.37)    
chr10_47466     SIFT=tolerated(0.11)
```

Qual comando usar no UNIX para obter esta lista?

Comment: Você pode utilizar o `awk` ou `cut`.

Comment: Eu tentei diversos comandos mutlei e não funcionou...se  puder ser mais específico....

Answer (score 1):

Você pode extrair essas informações de diversos modos, por exemplo, com o [`cut`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/), o [`awk`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_toc.html), e também com o *glorioso* [Perl](http://www.cpan.org/).

Segue um exemplo utilizando `awk`:

```pl
$ awk 'match($0, /SIFT=tolerated\([0-9.]+\)/) { print $1, "\t", 
substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) } ' arquivo
```

Onde:

- `match`: É a função que vai procurar pelo padrão `SIFT=tolerated\([0-9.]+\)`, isso significa que ela vai corresponder a sequência *SIFT=tolerated* que contenha números ou um ponto `.` entre parenteses. Ela retorna a posição do caractere, ou índice, de onde começa a *substring* correspondida.
- `substr`: Retorna uma *substring*, o `RSTART` significa o índice da *substring* correspondida e `RLENGTH` o tamanho.

Resultado:

```pl
$ awk 'match($0, /SIFT=tolerated\([0-9.]+\)/){ print $1, "\t", substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' foo.txt
chr10_46938     SIFT=tolerated(0.38)
chr10_46966     SIFT=tolerated(0.66)
chr10_46987     SIFT=tolerated(0.93)
chr10_47071     SIFT=tolerated(0.97)
chr10_47164     SIFT=tolerated(0.37)
chr10_47466     SIFT=tolerated(0.11)
$
```

Em outros sistemas pode ser que a sintaxe seja diferente, mas nada que não possa ser adaptado.

Comment: Muito obrigada Qmechanic73, funcionou perfeitamente!!! :)

Comment: @Clarissa Ótimo. Se possível marque a resposta como aceita, clique na marca de verificação que fica abaixo das setas; a cor mudará de cinza para verde. :)

Answer (score 1):

> @Qmechanic73: ... *glorioso* Perl

```
perl -nE 'say m/(\S+ ).*? (SIFT=\S+)/' foo.txt
```

E já agora `sed` para variar

```
sed -r 's!(\S+).*(SIFT=\S+).*!\1 \2!' foo.txt
```